# Querying dynamodb based on list of elements

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, nosql, dynamodb-queries

I'm working on a task where I need to translate fields based on system.
SystemA has it's specific fields and if I want to get SystemB's equivalent for it , I want to query and return result.

I'm new to DynamoDB.Below is dynamodb structure I have.

| Field_system(Partition) | Target_system(Sort) | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John_systemA | SystemB | Doe |
| Sam_systemA | SystemB | Smith |

There could be few thousand entries per system which has different fields.

My initial approach was to loop through list of fields from input and query dynamodb for each element and aggregate result. This would be better than scanning whole table.

Is there a better approach or other ways to query for all elements in list at once.

Appreciate feedback and suggestions

Answer (score 0):

For all elements in a list you have a couple of choices.

1. If you know both PK and SK for the items, then you can do a `BatchGetItem` and return up to 100 items per request.
2. If the sort key is unknown, you can do an `ExecuteStatement` which provides you the ability to do something that would be the equivalent of `BatchQuery` which is an API that does not exist. You can specify up to 50 partition keys in your request.
3. Again if you have a list of partition keys and are looking for the most performant approach, then sending parallel `Query` operations per key is the best way to achieve it.

Based on your schema, you may need to create an index with Target System as the partition key.